# postgresql self join

Tags: postgresql, join

Say I have a table like so

```
  id  |     device     |  cmd  | value | 
------+----------------+-------+---------

id = unique row ID
device = device identifier (mac address)
cmd = some arbitrary command
value = value of corresponding command
```

I would like to somehow self join on this table to grab specific cmds and their corresponding values for a particular device.

I do not want just `SELECT cmd,value FROM table WHERE device='00:11:22:33:44:55';`

Say the values I want correspond to the `getname` and `getlocation` commands.  I would like to have output something like

```
        mac         |    name   | location
--------------------+-----------+------------
 00:11:22:33:44:55  | some name | somewhere
```

My sql fu is pretty pants.  I've been trying different combinations like `SELECT a.value,b.value FROM table AS a INNER JOIN table AS b ON a.device=b.device` but I am getting nowhere.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT a.value AS thisval ,b.value AS thatval
FROM table AS a JOIN table AS b USING (device)
WHERE a.command='this' AND b.command='that';
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I suppose if I wanted four values instead of two, I'd need three JOIN's?

Comment: Yes, but maybe you want to reconsider your database structure if this is important ;-)

Comment: Another possibility would be to use group by and sort them out in select list.