# PostgreSQL can't make Self Join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table:

```
| acctg_cath_id | parent | description |
| 1             | 20     | Bills       |
| 9             | 20     | Invoices    |
| 20            |        | Expenses    |
| 88            | 30     |
| 89            | 30     |
| 30            |        |
```

And I want to create a self join in order to group my items under a parent.

Have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT
    accounting.categories.acctg_cath_id,
    accounting.categories.parent

FROM accounting.categories a1, accounting.categories a2

WHERE a1.acctg_cath_id=a2.parent
```

I get error: `invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "categories"`

When I try:

```
a.accounting.categories.acctg_cath_id
b.accounting.categories.acctg_cath_id
```

I get error: `cross-database references are not implemented: a.accounting.categories.acctg_cath_id`

---

Desired output:

- Expenses (Parent 20)

  - Bills (Child 1)
  - Invoices (Child 9)

---

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [postgresql self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648210/postgresql-self-join)

Comment: @emix Well, I tried a.accounting.categories.acctg_cath_id and b.accounting.categories.acctg_cath_id. But it's not working for me.

Comment: What output are you getting, and what do you want to get?

Comment: @jmelesky I get an error. I want to group the `acctg_cath_id` under a `parent` id's. Error `invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "categories"`

Comment: Ah, I got it. In your original query, you want to select `a1.acctg_cath_id, a1.parent` rather than `accounting.categories.acctg_cath_id` -- just naming the table is ambiguous since you're dealing with it in two different parts of the join.

Comment: Yes, you're right about that jmelesky.

Comment: @jmelesky: to be precise, using the original table name `categories` in the SELECT list (schema-qualified or not) is not ambiguous, but simply *invalid*, just like the error messages says. After attaching an alias, *only* the alias is valid in the rest of the query.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you merely want to sort the rows:

```
select *
from accounting.categorie
order by coalesce(parent, acctg_cath_id), parent nulls first, acctg_cath_id;
```

Result:

```
+---------------+--------+-------------+
| acctg_cath_id | parent | description |
+---------------+--------+-------------+
| 20            |        | Expenses    |
| 1             | 20     | Bills       |
| 9             | 20     | Invoices    |
| 30            |        |             |
| 88            | 30     |             |
| 89            | 30     |             |
+---------------+--------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is performing a cross join:
`FROM accounting.categories a1, accounting.categories a2`

Try the following:

```
SELECT
    a2.acctg_cath_id,
    a2.parent
FROM accounting.categories a1
    JOIN accounting.categories a2 ON (a1.acctg_cath_id = a2.parent)
;
```

Examine the [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e836738ad81a1a0da85e8a3a8c97b9b1).

Comment: Got an error: `[2019-06-27 22:43:48] [42P01] ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "categories"`
`[2019-06-27 22:43:48] Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "a1".`
`[2019-06-27 22:43:48] Position: 13`

Comment: I've updated the answer. The reason you were getting the cross-reference error is because of the syntax of your column names in the `SELECT` clause. In your example that threw the error you had: `<database>.<schema>.<table>.<column>`. When you applied the alias in the `FROM` clause you're assigning `accounting.categories` to the alias `a1` so you can replace the `accounting.categories` in the `SELECT` clause with `a1` or `a2` depending on the portion of the join that you need.

Comment: So you want the parent and all of its children? You'll need a recursive query.

Comment: I want the parents and well as the children. So I can order them as follows later on parent 20, children 1,9.

Comment: I've added a link to a dbfiddle that appears to provide the results you're looking for. Can you add example desired output to your question? Maybe I can get a stronger understanding of what you're looking for as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need grouping, only self join:

```
select 
  c.acctg_cath_id parentid, c.description parent,
  cc.acctg_cath_id childid, cc.description child
from (
  select distinct parent
  from categories
) p inner join categories c
on p.parent = c.acctg_cath_id
inner join categories cc on cc.parent = p.parent
where p.parent = 20
```

You can remove the WHERE clause if you want all the parents with all their children.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=eab8b3216707a3300320faf37b4daa69).
Results:

```
> parentid | parent   | childid | child   
> -------: | :------- | ------: | :-------
>       20 | Expences |       1 | Bills   
>       20 | Expences |       9 | Invoices
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a self-join.  You don't need aggregation.  You just need a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT ac.*
FROM accounting.categories ac
ORDER BY COALESCE(ac.parent, ac.acctg_cath_id),
         (CASE WHEN ac.parent IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         ac.acctg_cath_id;
```